# unable to access subclass method, is it disadvantage of Generics? or i am missing something

Tags: java, generics, linked-list

```
List<Employee> empLList = new LinkedList<>();
        empLList.add(...)
Iterator<Employee> descItr = empLList.descendingIterator();
```

in the  above code i'm unable to access descendingIterator with following error

```
cannot find symbol
  symbol:   method descendingIterator()
  location: variable empLList of type List<Employee>
```

to get descendingIterator i have to recast empLList to LinkedList

```
 Iterator<Employee> descItr = ((LinkedList) empLList).descendingIterator();
```

My question : In general is the above a disadvantage of using Generics, i.e, everytime we need to cast the object back to subclasss to access subclass' methods or is Generics supposed to work like that.

OR we should not use generics in case where we depend on too many of subclass' methods

OR i am missing something

**I am curious about the use of GENERICS in the example not the collections used.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not about Generics.

Look at APIs. `descendingIterator` is method of `Deque` not `List`

[LinkedList](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/LinkedList.html) implements [Deque](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Deque.html)

> My question : In general is the above a disadvantage of using Generics, i.e, everytime we need to cast the object back to subclasss to access subclass' methods or is Generics supposed to work like that.

Your snippet error is nowhere related to generics concepts. Logic based on casting is very very bad and should be replaced with polymorphism by correcting design.

> I am curious about the use of GENERICS in the example not the collections used.

Then ask right questions.

Change to following to make it work:

```
Deque<Employee> empLList = new LinkedList<>();
empLList.add(...)
Iterator<Employee> descItr = empLList.descendingIterator();
```

Answer (score 1):

This has nothing to do with generics.
The `List` interface is a contract, defining the methods all of its implementations have to provide. Some, like `LinkedList`, may provide additional methods (such as the afore mentioned `descendingIterator()`).

Your list of employees is regarded as being any implementation of `List`, thus all the `List` methods are available for use, nothing more.
If you know your implementation is `LinkedList`, you *may* **cast**, but this is **bad practice**. Better keep it as `LinkedList` then:

```
LinkedList<Employee> empLList = new LinkedList<>();
empLList.add(...)
Iterator<Employee> descItr = empLList.descendingIterator();
```

... or (if you accept any `List`, but want to use the `descendingIterator()`), create a new `LinkedList` out of it:

```
List<Employee> empLList = ... // any implementation 
empLList.add(...) 
Iterator<Employee> descItr = new LinkedList(empLList).descendingIterator();
```

Answer (score 0):

It is not because of Generics. It is because, descendingIterator() method is not available in List. In this line

```
  Iterator<Employee> descItr = empLList.descendingIterator();
```

You are calling the method on a list type referenece variable. As a result you are getting compile error. 
When it comes to the below line

```
  Iterator<Employee> descItr = ((LinkedList) empLList).descendingIterator();
```

You are casting your empList to LinkedList and method is available in LinkedList as it implements  Deque(Implementation of descendingIterator() is provided in LinkedList)